# Plot step response without using step function

Tags: matlab, plot, response

I want to plot the step response. I know that I can use step function with state space equations, but I try to get same results using plot function. Here is my sample of code:

```
for i=1:201
    u(i) = 1;
    x1(i+1) = (-(b/J)*x1(i) + (K/J)*x2(i));
    x2(i+1) = (-(K/L)*x1(i) - (R/L)*x2(i) + (1/L)*u(i));
    y(i) = x1(i);
end
```

and this is the state space equations:

```
A = [-b/J   K/J
    -K/L   -R/L];
B = [0
    1/L];
C = [1   0];
D = 0;
```

If i do:

```
t = 0:1:200;
plot(t, y)
```

it is not working and I want to have the same results like the step function below:

```
sys = ss(A,B,C,D);
step(sys)
```

You can find my state space equation [here](http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=MotorSpeed&section=SystemModeling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the mismatch is that `sys` is a continuous time model, whereas the computation of `y` treats it as a discrete-time system.

The following is a way of estimating the step-response of a continuous-time system in the discrete-time domain:

```
% Given from the problem statement
A = [-b/J   K/J
    -K/L   -R/L];
B = [0
    1/L];
C = [1   0];
D = 0;

% this is your continuous-time model
sys = ss(A,B,C,D);

% define the sample rate of the equivalent discrete-time model
Ts = 1/10; 
% this needs to be something smaller than the time-constants in your model,
% so that you have enough resolution to represent the continuous-time
% signal.

% convert the system to the equivalent discrete-time model
sysd = c2d(sys,Ts);

% define how long a step response you'd like to compute
T = 7; 
% this should be long enough to cover the length of the step response


t = 0:Ts:T; % time-grid for the plot
nSmp = length(t); % total number of samples to be computed

% initializations
y = NaN(1, nSmp); % output vector
u = ones(1, nSmp); % unit step input 
X = [0; 0]; % state vector, initialized to 0

% compute the samples of the step-response
%  (i prefer to use vectorized form to keep the code concise)
for i=1:nSmp
    y(i) = sysd.C * X + sysd.D * u(i);
    X = sysd.A * X + sysd.B * u(i);
end

% plot continous-time step response
figure;
step(sys);

% plot simulated discrete-time step response
figure;
plot(t, y, 'r')
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Simulated Step Response');
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is great. Next i need to add PID controller. Can you tell me how to get error, intagretion error and derivative error?? I need this 3 values to generate PID parameters by genetic alghorithm

Comment: @Masaj: I am afraid I might not be able to properly answer that. You'd be better off posting that as a new question so someone else could.